# How do I migrate users from RDS mysql databse to aws cognito user pools?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-rds, aws-userpools

I have an ios app and when one signs in, the uath happens via cognito(which is in place), additionally since all my user data is in rds mysql, I additionally want it to check if for the user, the email id is present in rds mysql db or not.For this I want to create a user migration lambda trigger.Please let me know if my architecture makes sense?

Comment: Did you ask this question yesterday under a different account?

Comment: You are asking multiple things in a single question.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple questions in a single question but I will answer anyway:

**How do you migrate users?**
You could just create a single-execution task to migrate your users from your MySQL db to Cognito, the only and biggest problem... could be the password info, I assume that you do not have it on plain text.

You could just send an email to all users about updating their password and give them a unique link to do so.

**Another option** is to keep that db and table for the users, when a new user logs in, just create/add the user to cognito with the password provided.

I assume that you might have this flow right now:

1. User logins with user/password
2. Server authenticates password and user to be on MySQL (password should not be in plain text) and returns the user info.

so, you could change it to be:

1. User logins with user/password
2. Server authenticates on cognito, if failed:
3. Server authenticates password and user to be on MySQL
4. Server adds user on cognito
5. Return user info

And in ... 3 months? or something, you could just drop the DB since you already have most users in cognito.

**Answering the about architecture question:**

I dont have enough context but seems complicated, why are you changing to cognito, any preference or feature that you want to use?